# How can I optimize page speed using YouTube video embedded code

Tags: pagespeed

I am using YouTube videos in my website with YouTube embed code. Due to this my page speed has decreased. As per GTMetrix, page speed is now 56% and loading time is above 9 seconds. Can anyone please help me in this issue?